# u# format character removed from Python 3.12 C-API, how to account for it?

Tags: python, python-c-api

A bunch of unicode-related functionality was removed from the Python 3.12 C-API. Unfortunately for me, there's a very old piece of code (~2010) in our library that uses these and I need to migrate this functionality somehow over to 3.12 since we're looking to upgrade to 3.12 eventually. One thing I'm specifically struggling with is the removal of the `u#` parameter. The following piece of code would parse any positional parameters passed to `foo` (including unicode strings), and store them in `input`:

```
static PyObject *
foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    Py_UNICODE *input;
    Py_ssize_t length;
    
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "u#", &input, &length)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html), the `u#` has been removed:

> Changed in version 3.12: `u`, `u#`, `Z`, and `Z#` are removed because they used a legacy Py_UNICODE* representation.

and the current code simply throws something like `bad-format-character` when this is compiled and used in pure python.

`Py_UNICODE` is just `wchar_t` so that's easily fixed. But with the removal of `u#` I am not sure how to get `PyArg_ParseTuple` to accept unicode input arguments. Using `s#` instead of `u#` does not work since it won't handle anything widechar. How do I migrate this call in Python 3.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s#` handles Unicode fine, but it gives you UTF-8 rather than `wchar_t`. If you specifically need a wchar representation, you can get one from a string object with [`PyUnicode_AsWideCharString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsWideCharString):

```c
Py_ssize_t size;
wchar_t *wchar_representation = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(stringobj, &size);

if (!wchar_representation) {
    // error occurred. do something about that.
}

// do stuff with wchar_representation, then once you're done,

PyMem_Free(wchar_representation);
```

Unlike the old `Py_UNICODE` API, this allocates a new buffer, which you have to free with `PyMem_Free` when you're done with it.

Comment: Ah, perhaps that's what I'm missing, that wchar_t is UCS-2 I believe and not utf-8. I think in a lot of these places I can just use `char*` and I'll be fine as I'm not interested in the specific encoding format, just that it works.